Why do I get different standard errors when i group the data before fitting a Quasi-Poisson GLM for counts with an offset = log(population)?
Is it theoretically correct to group the data before fitting a quasi-Poisson or should I leave it ungrouped?
Commentary as well as an example in R code is posted below.
I noticed I get different standard errors when I group the data before fitting a Quasi-Poisson GLM for Tumor counts with an offset = log(Population). This doesn't happen if I use the Poisson family instead of quasi-Poisson so I was surprised.
Here is R code and sample data that illustrates my question:
## Create Grouped and Ungrouped datasets where the Sum of Tumor and Population are the same when grouped by Psych.Profile and Cig
## Grouped Data
data_grouped <- data.frame(Tumor = c(45,77,95,92,103,12,29,31,43,56,30,36,62,57,71)
                           ,Pop = c(24795,32125,34706,23440,14133,11946,22781,14566,15654,10097,50711,35332,41707,26319,22978)
                           ,Psych.Profile = factor(c('A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','C','C','C','C','C'), levels = c("C", "B", "A"))
                           ,Cig = c(0,0.5,1,1.5,2,0,0.5,1,1.5,2,0,0.5,1,1.5,2))

## Ungrouped Data. this one has the first row of the grouped data blownout into 45 rows with 1 Tumor each and population = 24795/45 = 551
data_ungrouped <- data.frame(Tumor = c(rep(1,45),77,95,92,103,12,29,31,43,56,30,36,62,57,71)
                           ,Pop = c(rep(551,45),32125,34706,23440,14133,11946,22781,14566,15654,10097,50711,35332,41707,26319,22978)
                           ,Psych.Profile = factor(c(rep('A',45),'A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','C','C','C','C','C'), levels = c("C", "B", "A"))
                           ,Cig = c(rep(0,45),0.5,1,1.5,2,0,0.5,1,1.5,2,0,0.5,1,1.5,2))

## Fit Quasi-poisson models to each dataset
model_grouped <- glm(Tumor ~ Cig + Psych.Profile, family = quasipoisson((link = "log")), offset = log(Pop), data = data_grouped)
model_ungrouped  <- glm(Tumor ~ Cig + Psych.Profile, family = quasipoisson((link = "log")), offset = log(Pop), data = data_ungrouped)

> coef(summary(model_grouped))
                 Estimate Std. Error   t value     Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)    -7.3071846 0.09242152 -79.06367 1.649769e-16
Cig             0.7661623 0.05563362  13.77157 2.791780e-08
Psych.ProfileB  0.3887326 0.10225686   3.80153 2.935492e-03
Psych.ProfileA  0.7645370 0.08235288   9.28367 1.545673e-06

> coef(summary(model_ungrouped))
                 Estimate Std. Error    t value     Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)    -7.3071846 0.04133216 -176.79175 1.814343e-77
Cig             0.7661623 0.02488011   30.79417 2.303794e-36
Psych.ProfileB  0.3887326 0.04573066    8.50048 1.343316e-11
Psych.ProfileA  0.7645370 0.03682933   20.75892 1.081513e-27

## Std error drops for the coefficients. E.g. Cig drops from 0.05563362 to 0.02488011


One motivation for grouping the data is so I can significantly reduce the row counts and work with bigger datasets more easily.

I think the problem is that your ungrouped data don't fit the model.
If you divided the 24795 people in the first grouped record into 45 equal chunks of 551 before recording the response you would not have ended up with Tumor equal to 1 for each chunk.  Instead, you would have ended up with an equal-probability multinomial vector with 45 entries summing to 45.
If you do this
data_ungrouped$Tumor[1:45]<-rmultinom(1, 45, rep(1,45))

you get much closer agreement on the standard errors.
They still won't be identical, because changing the data like this changes the estimate of the dispersion parameter. The dispersion parameter in the ungrouped data puts a lot more weight on the 45 first observations than the disperson parameter in the grouped data puts on the first one observation.

I'm not quite sure I follow the rationale here -- I'll try to illustrate my thinking with an example: Suppose the ungrouped data was just what I started from and is the truth. When I group it why does the standard error change? Intuitively it seems something is lost when the data is grouped in terms of our understanding of the variability and so a larger Std error can make sense to me but what puzzles me is why this doesn't occur with the Poisson if that is the case.

If the ungrouped data were as you indicated, a quasipoisson model would be a poor fit: the dispersion parameter implied by the first 45 rows would be very different from that for the rest of the data. A Poisson model would also be a poor fit, but this would be masked by the fact that we don't compute a dispersion parameter for the Poisson model

I guess what's still unclear to me is whether I should group the data or not before fitting the quasi-poisson as they give different results. Assuming the ungrouped data is what was observed, should I group it or not before fitting? I'm not sure what you're referring to regarding fit as whether the data is grouped or not the fit is the goodness of fit is the same as the coefficients do not change (do you mean the SE?). Also note that this data comes from a poisson dataset from https://real-statistics.com/binomial-and-related-distributions/poisson-distribution/ if that helps gives some context.

I don't mean either the coefficients or the SEs. I mean that the model does not fit: the variance is not a constant multiple of the mean.   What I would do is use a sandwich estimator so you don't have to make the assumption of constant dispersion parameter and the grouping doesn't matter so much.

I found an answer to this question here: https://doi.org/10.1515/ijb-2020-0079. Essentially, grouping the data has no effect on coefficients but changes the standard error (upwards for overdispersed data). The grouped and ungrouped data in theory should have the same standard error for the coefficients but in reality rarely do because there is unobserved heterogeneity within groupings and/or between groupings. The authors attribute the variance effect and a (potentially huge) dependency effect for the increased dispersion in the aggregated dataset.
